# How to add a link to download a pdf file nuxt?

Tags: pdf, vue.js, nuxt.js

I just wants to add a link to download a pdf file in nuxt project.

### How do I do that?

I have tried the following:

```
<a :href="require('@/static/documents/WTSDL2019_Pamplet.pdf')" download class="btn btn-sm btn-sub-color" >Download</a>
```

which works well for images but not for pdf files. I found `vue-pdf` but I feel its an extra work for the purpose of just linking a pdf file. I have no work view a pdf files with all those events.

Comment: If it works for images but not for pdfs, what is the error with the pdf?

Comment: Did you try to directly link to static folder like: `<a href="/static/file.pdf" download>`?

Comment: <a style="margin-left: 10px;text-decoration: none;" :href="static/documents/WTSDL2019_Pamplet.pdf" download="">pdf download</a> try this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem and this worked for me. **I added the file in the static folder and it worked.**

- static

  - WTSDL2019_Pamplet.pdf

```
<a href="/WTSDL2019_Pamplet.pdf" download="">Download</a>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. For example, why are there multiple backticks in that `a` tag?

Comment: Don't know why the downvote, people should read the answer and understand it, it doesn't need much explanation. PS: add a slash to the href="/WTSDL2019_Pamplet.pdf"

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
<a href="/cv.pdf">Download my CV</a>
```

if you put the PDF in the static folder. You don't need the /static/ as NUXT does the magic.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a :href="require('../assets/documents/WTSDL2019_Pamplet.pdf')" download>
Download
</a>
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.

Comment: it's nothing major to explain, he just needs to replace the `@` with `../`
but i don't recommend this method since it will actually load the file to the compiler when you run npm run dev and make your project slow, i uploaded my files to the server and just used the link from my storage server

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, when I put file (1111.pdf) in **sub-folder of static**; like this *static/pdf/1111.pdf* , It doesn't response anything. But when I change to this  1111.pdf file to **just under static folder**, It works.
This is my code:

```
<a href="../../1111.pdf" download="" target="_blank" >Download</a>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31045285)