# How to add a link to download a file in a md file using Nuxt3 & Nuxt Content?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt-content

*I want to offer PDF files to download on my Nuxt3 site which uses Nuxt Content.*

According to the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56830238/how-to-add-a-link-to-download-a-pdf-file-nuxt) this should be possible by just **putting the pdf file into the `/static` folder** and **link it via**

```html
<a href="/my_pdf_file.pdf" download>Download</a>
```

In Nuxt3, [the static folder has been renamed to public](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/understanding-the-directory-structure-in-nuxt-3/), so I just assumed putting my pdf into `/public` and using the same link should work.

But unfortunately it doesn't - I get a `404 Error` when clicking on the Download link and Vue warns me anyway `[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/my_pdf_file.pdf"` (I did put the file into the folder, trust me).

I'm using Nuxt Content (2.1.0) and want to put the link in a `.md` file that lives in the `/content` folder.

Here is a minimal, reproducible example in which the Download does not work:
https://github.com/chamaoskurumi/nuxt3content_example

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download file using anchor tag <a>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607309/how-to-download-file-using-anchor-tag-a)

Comment: No unfortunately not - I included this anchor now in my example code.

Comment: You need to add full url of pdf file in <a> tag.

Comment: I updated my question specifying that I use Nuxt Content and the file where I want to link the download is a `.md` file.

Comment: Thanks for the repro, kudos for the follow-up on your question to improve it. I will meanwhile not be able to help you here, but feel free to post a [Github issue](https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/new/choose) with the details of this question!

Comment: Done https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/1783. Thank you @kissu !

Comment: I've updated my answer based of the answer of Ahad on the linked GH issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update after an official answer

As [confirmed here](https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/1783#issuecomment-1367301722) by an official core maintainer of the Nuxt team, you can use this syntax

```markdown
# Nuxt Content

[Download](/dummy.pdf){target="_blank" download="dummy.pdf"} pdf via MDC syntax

<a href="/dummy.pdf" target="_blank" download="awesome.pdf">Download</a> via regular HTML syntax
```

---

The given solution perfectly works, there is something with your project configuration or maybe your version of Nuxt.
Here is a visual of how it should be exactly.

[image]

Just double-checked and it works perfectly fine.

Here is a result: https://share.cleanshot.com/0YCBRVYB

Comment: All right, good to know - so yes, you must be be right and it must be something with my project configuration. I think the culpid might be Nuxt Content (2.1.0). I have md files in my content folder - and this is where I want to put the links. I will try to stich together a minimal reproduible example.

Comment: @gosz I didn't worked with the second version of Nuxt content. It may be a good culprit indeed. Meanwhile, if it's regular HTML inside of the MD file, it is supposed to work well. Maybe try a relative path since you will be in the content folder anyway. Otherwise, there is maybe some flag or setting for that.

Comment: Relative path did not help unfortunately...I managed to create a rep example: https://github.com/chamaoskurumi/nuxt3content_example